# Why does TOAD mess up the output order in dbms_output?

Tags: oracle, toad

I am using Oracle 10.2 and Toad for Oracle Xpert Version 11.5.0.56

Why does this script print things in the wrong order in the **DMBS Output** window?

```
BEGIN
    FOR indx IN 1 .. 70
    LOOP

        dbms_output.put_line('-------------------------------------------------- TEST --------------------------------------------------');
        dbms_output.put_line('INDEX: ' || indx);                                        
        dbms_output.put_line('CREATING: 3424234 - TEST - TEST.TTEST');
        dbms_output.put_line('CREATION ORDER: ' || 10);                                                            
        dbms_output.put_line('OTHER DATA IS VALID: N');          

        IF indx = 54 THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('=======================================');
            EXIT; 
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

END;
```

If you look at the output window it will show the items printed in the wrong order. Prints the Lines for the index in this order:

> 21, 22, 23, ... 54, 1, 2, ... 20

Basically it shows first the Lines for the Index = 21, then 22, and so on until it prints the lines for Indx = 54. At which point it prints the lines for Indx =1, then Indx = 2, up until 20.

Why isn't TOAD show the text from Indx = 1 to Indx = 54 in the right order?

Is the Exit in the middle of the For related with this behavior?

Comment: I don't think that code will ever create your specified output (you're missing a lot) so you're not telling us something... can you simplify your code to the point where it demonstrates this issue and you can post the full output without it taking up a huge amount of space (only output the index maybe)

Comment: run it through sqlplus and see if you get the same results.

Comment: What version of Toad? I'm on the latest beta and executing as script (F5) and F9 both produce the results in the order 1..54.

Comment: @MichaelS Toad for Oracle Xpert Version 11.5.0.56

Comment: @Ben I don't understand what you mean when you say I am missing a lot? I copy-pasted this code from TOAD because is producing the exact output I am describing. The original script is a lot larger, yes, but I stripped down to this and still shows the described behavior.

Comment: @MichaelS do you think I may be reaching some buffer limit and that is why I am getting this behavior? Did you try running the LOOP more times instead of 54 or 70?

Comment: @OldProgrammer in SQL Developer it prints things in the right order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an issue/bug in the 11.5.0.56 version of TOAD causing it to print the results wrong in the DBMS Output window.

It gets fixed by applying patches up to version 11.5.2 or by getting a newer version.